# Why does SET LINESIZE not work in my script?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a script saved in a file: `QUERY.sql`. Inside the file, I have the following lines at the top:

```
SET SERVEROUT ON SIZE 1000000;
SET ECHO OFF;
SET LINESIZE 4000;
SET PAUSE OFF;
SET VERIFY OFF;
```

Whenever I run the script from the command window using `@QUERY`, the script runs mostly right, except the linesize is still at the default and it cuts off the data into a new line. The lines are being formatted for entry in another system, so I can't change their formats.

In order to make it work, I have to manually enter `SET LINESIZE 4000;` in the command window, then run my query. It is mildly annoying to me, but I am worried other users won't know how to get around the problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: [This question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54149/how-to-make-sqlplus-output-appear-in-one-line) may help

Comment: try dropping the semicolons after the sqlplus commands

Comment: Dropping the semicolons solved not only that, but another problem I was having as well where I had to run another query first before I ran this one. Thank you, @tbone! I don't really know why the semicolons messed it up, but it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the SQLPlus commands at the top of the script, try dropping the semicolons

```
SET SERVEROUT ON SIZE 1000000
SET ECHO OFF
SET LINESIZE 4000
SET PAUSE OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
```

Heres the [SET command reference list](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG060) for anyone looking for it